# Visual Studio: Release Build keeps changing AssemblyVersion and then complains about it (CS7034)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I took over a C# project, and I'm pretty new to the C#/Visual Studio world.

During development in the "Debug" configuration, the project built just fine. But now, since I switched to the "Release" configuration, I keep getting Error CS7034: The specified version string does not conform to the required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]]

Before the build, in AssemblyInfo.cs I have:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.4.0.4129")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.4.0.4129")]
```

But the building process keeps changing this to

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.4.0.-1")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.4.0.-1")]
```

and -1 is not a valid number. Where does that change come from?

I switched from SVN to git, and I wasn't able to permanently get rid of AnkhSVN integration. Could that be the culprit? 4128 was the latest SVN revision number. Maybe the plugin is looking for the latest revision but couldn't find any, resulting in -1?

Comment: Do you have a custom plugin or post-build event which updates the build number? This isn't the default behaviour. (I wouldn't expect SCC to update the file it on a _build_, as they generally don't get involved with that)

Comment: Surely you use some kind of custom build tool that automatically changes version numbers before building.  There is no standard solution for that, most everybody cobbles something together themselves.  It is broken.

Comment: There are no pre- or post build events specified. Compiling it using JetBrains Rider has the same effect. Compiling in the old SVN repository works. I'm confused...

Comment: Oh, found it (see answer). Rider's before/after target config GUI didn't show it, but you were right, there WAS a before-build event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The .csproj file contained this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Release'">
...
```

In this target the replacement was specified.